# get Row with most likes per day

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I'm having problem which I've not yet been able to solve. Have a look at the following table.

```
+---+------------+-------------------------------------+
|id |   likes    |   fb_likes    |     created_time    |
+---+------------+-------------------------------------+
|10 |    0       |      0        | 2013-04-07 13:53:36 |
| 9 |    3       |      2        | 2013-04-07 13:17:18 |
| 8 |    2       |      1        | 2013-04-06 21:49:30 |
| 7 |    2       |      0        | 2013-04-06 20:25:24 |
| 6 |    6       |      5        | 2013-04-06 18:52:27 |
| 5 |    3       |      0        | 2013-04-05 21:19:34 |
| 4 |    5       |      2        | 2013-04-05 19:09:13 |
| 3 |    9       |     10        | 2013-04-03 14:18:56 |
| 2 |    0       |      1        | 2013-04-02 14:28:36 |
| 1 |    0       |      0        | 2013-04-02 08:39:32 |
+---+------------+-------------------------------------+
```

I want to select the Id which has the most likes per day. I've seen a lot of post that wanted to do something similar, but haven't found the solution yet.

My failed Attempt (this select the correct likes, but wrong id):

```
SELECT id, MAX(likes+fb_likes) as Tlikes, created_time FROM table GROUP BY DAY(created_time);
```

I also tried something like this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Any help would be appreciated

**Update**
I forgot to add fb_likes column. How stupid of me.

Comment: This question is asked EVERY SINGLE DAY

Comment: Ow, I'm sorry. I've been searching for a couple of hours, but didn't find any thing that really worked for me. Might you have a reference?

Comment: In fact the link you provided IS the reference!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  DATE(created_time) date, MAX(likes) max_likes
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY DATE(created_time)
        ) b ON  DATE(a.Created_Time) = b.date AND
                a.likes = b.max_Likes
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b75e9/1)

if you want to show only records with atleast 1 vote, you need to add `WHERE` clause on the outer select, eg

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b75e9/2)

Comment: Thank You J W! I tried a similar query like that before. I'll need to check what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, likes, day(created_time)
FROM Likes
WHERE likes =
(SELECT MAX(maxLikes.likes) 
 FROM Likes maxLikes 
 WHERE day(maxLikes.created_time) = day(Likes.created_time)
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e35f/8